# Can I use Eureka discovery to discover third-party components?

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, cmis

I have a file repository, like an AWS S3, but it's actually on an internal server and it is not a AWS S3 (it is a CMIS via HTTP). I have to specify that this CMIS repository is not a project as such (Java, NET, Python etc ...) it can be a midlware that lives on any server (And it cannot be modified), my doubt is, there is a probability that can discovery with EUREKA? I mean that to eureka I pass the URL-PORT and thus use its service id and not url and port from an internal Java microservice?

Thanks!!

Comment: Eureka requires services to send heartbeats. You'd have to write an app to do that. It's also built to handle many instances of one service. It's overkill for what seems like configuration.

Comment: Might be late, but I think you can use  euraka sidecar to register it to eureka server.